# How to show windows background process in the foreground

Tags: java, windows, service, process, jna

My problem description:

I have a server with OS version Windows 2012R2, I have two process running on it.
[image: this is one of them]

I have a .bat file to start them.
Below is the detail of .bat file:

```
e:
cd E:\autostart
echo =========================     1.RUN PCG    =========================
start startWebworksServer_PCG
echo =========================     2.RUN PHONE     =========================
start startWebworksServer_PHONE
```

Now I create a .jar file and make the jar as a windows service. just like this :
[image]

This service will start these 2 processes in the background, I cannot see the windows of these 2 processes.

I want to find a way to have this service start these 2 processes in the foreground, so that I can see these 2 windows after logging in to the server. It is best to use java language.

PS:I tried to use JNA because I was first exposed to JNA and I failed. I tried to use `Advapi32.INSTANCE.CreateProcessWithLogonW` but it still started the process in the background and I still can't see the process window.

Answer (score 0):

Services usually does not show any window, but as far as I remember, you should have a checkbox "allow this service to interact with the desktop" in the service properties. This of course would work only if there is a user session.

Comment: Is it possible to try to capture the user login and then show the window on the logged-in user session？The reason why I did this is to automatically start these two processes after the server restarts, but we need the windows of these two processes when we log in to the server